# Free C# Automatically Marshalled Data using MarashalAs Attribute

Tags: c#, c++, c, marshalling, free

CLR can marshal managed types into unmanaged c/c++ types using marshal as attrubte
what I need is that what is the proper method to free this allocated memory.. for example::

in C/C++ code

```
char* dummy(char* text){
//do some thing
return text;//dummy way to return it to the caller to free it.
}
```

and in C#

```
[DllImport("test.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr dummy([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text);
```

and finally the test

```
    C# Test
IntPtr marshaledData=dummy("any text");
//what is the proper way to free this memory location
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of what `free()`ing memory means?, if you do the equivalent in c, you would cause undefined behavior, you shall not `free()` static memory.

Comment: i can allocate the memory using Marshal class, and set the value and after finishing free it with the proper method, but it's too mush compared to MarshalAs magical attribute

Comment: using MSCRV free method on that marshaled memory location caused the application to abort, what I'm asking is what's the proper method to free this location of memory

Comment: The C code is very evil, it returns a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  If it did not reallocate *text* then the memory was already released after it returns since the pinvoke marshaller owns it.  Looks like it works, but then it randomly doesn't when you're not looking.  Also high odds that it will corrupt the heap while writing *text.  If it does allocate then you can't release it unless it used an allocator that your C# code has access to.